# Is it possible to create child/split edges using JGraphx

Tags: java, swing, jgraphx

In [HelloWorld](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/blob/master/java/examples/com/mxgraph/examples/swing/HelloWorld.java) example of JGraphx, if we insert two edges between the vertices, the edges are overlapped. Is there a way to make them split, like shown in this image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible :( (atleast as of now).